# Equivalence of two equations for relativistic wavelength

Tags: special-relativity, wavelength

I have seen two equations for the relativistic De Broglie wavelength of a particle, I understand how each one is derived but I am struggling to show that they are equivalent.

$$λ_r=mv/√(1-v^2/c^2 )$$

$$λ_r=hc/√(T^2+2mTc^2 )$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Actually, the first equation is the definition of the relativistic momentum, but not of wavelength, a simple comparison of units on both sides shows that this equation is wrong.  May be you mean $\lambda = h/p$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Ill it should be $λ_r=(h/mv) √(1-v^2/c^2 )$

Comment: Hi, please (**always**) define your terms.  While those "in the know" recognize all these, at the least identify $h$ and $T$